# How to tidy up things like &#x00FA; in xml?

Tags: xml, unicode, utf-8, tidy

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<authors><![CDATA[&#x00E3;  &#x00FA; ]]></authors>  
</root>
```

I want to convert `&#x00FA;` to `ú`. The following way of calling `tidy` does not work. Does anybody know what is the correct way of calling it?

```
tidy --preserve-entities no --output-encoding utf8 tmp1.xml > tmp2.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

A CDATA section like

```
<![CDATA[&#x00E3; &#x00FA;]]>
```

is **not** equivalent to

```
<![CDATA[ã ú]]>
```

Inside a CDATA section, characters like `&`, `<`, or `>` lose their special meaning and are treated literally. So the CDATA section above is equivalent to

```
&amp;#x00E3; &amp;#x00FA;
```

Your conversion doesn't "tidy up" your XML file, it actually changes the character data. That's why you can't make the transformation you're looking for with simple tools. Also, you usually can't blindly apply a regex, because you don't want to change other parts of your XML file that might contain CDATA sections as well.

If you really want to convert files like you described, you should probably write a small program in a scripting language of your choice using an XML library. This program should only decode entities in those parts of your XML file where you really want the conversion to occur. See the following Perl script, for example:

```perl
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_fh(\*STDIN);

# Process all text nodes within "authors" elements.
for my $authors_text ($doc->findnodes('//authors//text()')) {
    my $text = $authors_text->data;
    $text =~ s/&#x([0-9A-Fa-f]+);/chr(hex($1))/ge;
    $authors_text->setData($text);
}

print $doc->toString;
```

Answer (score 0):

In java a generic pattern search and replace.

The following searches for `&#` + an optional `x` (hexadecimal) + number + `;`.

```
String fillInNumericEntities(String xml) {
    Pattern entityPattern = Pattern.compile("\\&#([Xx]?)([\\w]+);");
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(xml.length());
    Matcher m = entityPattern.matcher(xml);
    while (m.find()) {
         int numBase = m.group(1).isEmpty() ? 10 : 16;
         String number = m.group(2);
         try {
             int codePoint = Integer.parseInt(number, numBase);
             int[] codePoints = new int[] { codePoint };
             String ch = new String(codePoints, 0, 1);
             m.appendReplacement(sb, ch);
         } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         }
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

A remark: the browser can be a source of automatic translation of special characters to numeric entities, especially if the HTML `<form accept-charset="UTF-8">` is missing.